# how to clone mysql_result

Tags: php, mysql

I will explain my problem
From *index.php* I POST my login and in login.php I store session details (like name) e.g.:

```
$_SESSION['name'] =  mysql_result($res,0,"name");
```

then I am forwarded back to *index.php*. 
Here I want to show logged-in-user's name:

```
   echo $_SESSION['name']
```

and also all names from the DB:

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
for ($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $name =$row['name']; 
  echo $name;
}
```

And here comes the problem: after I log in, everything (both user's name and all names) is displayed correctly. But when I refresh the page `echo $_SESSION['name']` shows the last name in the databse == `$name` instead of the one that was

So I guess I need to clone  `mysql_result($res,0,"name");` when storing into $_SESSION['name']

Thank you very much

EDIT
the only thing i store in session is the login name. And when the person is logged-in he can see all people from database.

Comment: What is the actual query you are running to return the result?

Comment: Yeah you're simply passing a reference instead of an object.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz so how can I "clone" it? Instead of passing just a reference

Comment: Answered below and some extra text so that I can post this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to clone an object then you can try the following

```
$object2 = clone $object1;
```

From the php documentation it seems that some objects do not support cloning, so if this is the case then you could try the following (again, from comment in php documentation) to do a deep copy

```
protected function deepCopy($inputObject) {
    return unserialize(serialize($inputObject)); 
}
```

There are some other good points made in the comments of the documentation page which can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Best regards

Comment: too bad I am not using php5. Any other suggestions for my simple case?

Comment: Seeing as mysql_result returns a string, I am guessing that you are actually over-writing it upon subsequent calls. Why don't you put some logic in there to handle this case so that over-writing doesn't occur. I didn't realize that mysql_result as only returning a string. This should be passed by value instead of by reference.

Comment: I call it once when storing into session. Then I close the connection. And then I am forwarded to index.php and there I open connection again and select all names from DB

Comment: While you may think you're not over-writing it I don't think there is any other way this could be happening. If this was an object that was passed as reference, then yes it could, but seeing as it is being passed by value then the value on the stack is unchanging and unless the value is reassigned it should maintain the same value. I would say check through your code and make absolutely sure that you're not reassigning it on subsequent DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are better off not storing all the other names in the session.  Being a database app with logins I assume other people can use and update the data, meaning that any time they change something, your session-saved data will be obsolete on refresh.

Try just letting them login and set their on credentials, then when they get back to index check that they are logged in and fetch the names at that point.  That way you don't have to worry about cloning the fetch AND you have the most up to date info.

Comment: it isn't what is he looking for.